# PHP not working, database not updating

Tags: php, mysql, sql, break

im writing this php script to update user passwords, requiring old pasword, new and new confirmation. It all works it seems up to the actual `UPDATE` mysql statement. Not sure what I've done wrong, al help appreciated!

Also, I am aware its not secure and such, I am just trying ot make it work first im a php newbie!

I'm tearing my hair out, when I run this, everything seems to work except it breaks just before `if (empty($error)){` , i have tested the echo for session email and it displays that, however it does not update the database with the new password. Please help! below is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();

include('database_connection.php');

$error = array();

if (empty($_POST['oldpassword'])){
$error[] ='You did not enter your current password!';
} else {
    $oldpassword = $_POST['oldpassword'];
}



if (empty($_POST['newpassword'])){

    $error[] = 'You did not enter a new password!';
} else {
    if(preg_match("/^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$/", $_POST["newpassword"])){
        $newpassword = $_POST['newpassword'];
    } else{
        $error[] = 'Password must be at least 8 characters and must contain at least one lower case letter, one upper case letter and one digit!';
    }
}

if (empty($_POST['newpasswordcon'])){
    $error[] = 'You did not enter your new password confirmation!';
} else {
    if(preg_match("/^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$/", $_POST["newpasswordcon"])){
        $newpasswordcon = $_POST['newpasswordcon'];
    } else{
        $error[] = 'Password must be at least 8 characters and must contain at least one lower case letter, one upper case letter and one digit!';
    }
}


if($_POST['newpassword'] != $_POST['newpasswordcon']){
$error[] ='New password and confirmation do not match!' ;
}


$sql = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE email='" . $_SESSION['email'] . "'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);


if( $r = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {
extract($r);



if($_POST['oldpassword'] != $password);{
$error[] ='Incorrect current password!';

}

//breaks here
echo $_SESSION['email'];

if (empty($error)){

echo $_SESSION['email'];
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET password='$newpassword' WHERE email='" . $_SESSION['email'] . "'");


echo '<p class ="alert alert-success fade in">Success! Your password has been updated!</p>';

}
} else{

    foreach ($error as $key => $values) {

            echo '<p class ="alert alert-error fade in">'.$values.'</p>';


}
}
?>
```

Comment: Check the error returned by the function mysql_query() for a start

Comment: `print_r($error)` just before your `empty` condition, does it contain anything?

Comment: seems to work if i run it in phpmyadmin, replacing `$newpassword` with 'hello' and $_SESSION['email'] with a valid email

Comment: escape your data, hash passwords (plain text password wth?) and use mysqli or PDO with prepared statements.

Comment: @CrayonViolent

 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in C:\wamp\www\Website\updatepassword.php on line 61

Im guesing this is the issue

Comment: 1) `mysql_*` functions, 2) passwords stored in plaintext.

Comment: @BenDuttywoodMaxfield well did you add a semicolon at the end of that?

Comment: if($_POST['oldpassword'] != $password);{  <== semicolon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a semicolon which should not be there.

```
if ($_POST['oldpassword'] != $password);{ // <- remove this semicolon after )
   $error[] ='Incorrect current password!';
}
```

Comment: Even if it's some years later now: you may use a text editor like TextMate which allows syntax validation of different coding languages. It's a daily help in my live... ;)

Comment: Thanks, I do use things like Sublime now, although I no longer use PHP -  most of my work is done with C# in VS. I appreciate the response nonetheless!

Answer (score -4):

I don't see any addslashes() in your code and am wondering if you get any matches? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

Comment: The OP already noted that he is aware his code is not secure. addslashes is currently considered not to be an adequate defense against SQL injection, as you can discover easily by Googling or indeed reading the page you have linked to (although I confess that I don't fully understand the vulnerabilities that exist or how to perform an attack against a site that uses addslashes).

Comment: @MarkAmery - I saw his note, but this wasn't related to security as much as wondering if the input had any characters that are conflated by things like magic quotes or environmental settings. That was before I saw the semicolon, tho.